# How can I use forms for pull-down navigation menus?

Tags: html

How can I use forms for pull-down navigation menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the value of the option element to the action you want the menu item to perform such as:

```
<select onchange="return DoAction();">
  <option value="http://example.com/Home/">Go Home</option>
</select>
```

Although I wouldn't recommend using form elements as navigation, some operating systems have inconsistent implementations of things like form-based pull-down menus.